# How to Activator.CreateInstance a type which have not constructors?

Tags: c#

**For example:**

```
class TestType
{
   public int a;
   public int b;
}

TestType obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestType), 1, 2) as TestType;
```

Then `obj.a==1` and `obj.b==2` ? Does someone knows how to solve my problem?

Comment: Why can't you assign the values after you have created the instance. like obj.a=1 and obj..b=2

Comment: Can you add a constructor or methods, or is it a class in a 3rd party assembly?

Comment: 1) The type *does* have a constructor, unless it is a static type it will at least have the default constructor provided by the compiler and 2) no, there is no constructor call or similar in the framework which will do what you want regarding assignments, what Antoine answers below is the closest you will get, unless you add the missing constructor that is.

Comment: because the TestType class is just a data class, have no method, i have many data class. i don not want to create constructor for these class. and I must create these by reflection

Answer (score 8):

Impossible, try instead

```
TestType obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestType)) as TestType;
obj.a = 1;
obj.b = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TestType obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestType), 1, 2) as TestType;
```

This is the overload Activator.CreateInstance(type, params object[] args); where args are the input for the constructor. So you can use either Antoines solution or change the test type class to:

```
TestType obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestType), 1, 2) as TestType;

class TestType
{
    public TestType(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing things. The syntax `new TestType { a=1, b=2 }` is *not* calling the constructor. It is a shortcut for calling the implicit or default constructor and setting some properties in one shot. But all classes have constructors. At least the implicit one.

I don't know what is your final goal, but if you are using `Activator` to create an instance, then you probably don't have the type at compile time. Thus you can't access the properties via the type itself, you will need to call `PropertyInfo.SetValue` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)

See following example:

```
class TestType
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

void Main()
{
    var typeName = typeof(TestType).FullName; // we have a string from here on

    var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == typeName); // get the type based on the name

    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // object of this type, but without compile time type info

    var member = type.GetField("a"); // we know, that this is a field, not a property   
    member.SetValue(obj, 1); // we set value to 1
    member = type.GetField("b");
    member.SetValue(obj, 2); // we set value to 2

    Console.Write($"See values: a={((TestType)obj).a}, b={((TestType)obj).b}");
}
```

In this last code row I have reintroduced the compile-time type, just to show that the constructed object has the members set as we expect them to be set.

In general you will most likely look for types that extend some base type or implement an interface, but it might well be cases when you have the fully qualified type name from the configuration for example.

Comment: You can combine constructor syntax and object initialization syntax, so it is short for "construct object" and "assign members", which means you could do this: `new TestType(1) { b = 2 }`, provided the type has a constructor which takes a single parameter.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that's true, but might be too complex scenario for OP based on the question...